# Difference between expressions and interpolation markup with embedded expressions in angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

*"Angular directive attributes take either expressions or interpolation markup with embedded expressions. It is considered bad practice to embed interpolation markup inside an expression".*

I couldn't understand the **difference between expressions and interpolation** markup with embedded expressions. Please can someone explain ? I am new to angular.I checked the documentation but couldn't find the difference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An expression would be the "myscope" in `ng-model="myscope"`

And you can also do custom attributes like `my-att="{{myscope}}"`

**edit:** these expressions in curly braces are interpolated, meaning not the expression itself but its value gets passed into the directive. Your directive will thereby not have direct access to the scope property you used for the interpolation.

But you should not mix the two like `ng-model="my{{scope}}"`

I think that is what it refers to. This will often not work, since the scope is not yet initialized when the directive is parsed

Comment: Ok.got the point but what does the word interpolation refers to your code?I still didnt get the difference between  expressions and interpolation markup with embedded expressions.Thanks for your time

Comment: if you can clearly say which is which i will gladly accept your answer.But for now i am upvoting it

Comment: Ok, sorry I didn't explain that well enough, I'll update the answer

Comment: @Debojyoti I updated the answer, hopefully this helps you more.

Comment: So the value passed to a ng directive is an expression and the value passed to a custom directive is called interpolation markup with embedded expression.Is it correct what i am thinking?

Comment: @Debojyoti it doesn't depend on who wrote the expression, but what you put inside the attribute. So you can also write custom directives that expect expressions, Google for "directive scope" and you can see the (very confusing) options you have. But directives expecting expressions should not get an interpolated value. And others that expect plain text instead of an expression can receive interpolated values, even mixed with static stuff, like "my age: {{user.age}}" for example. That would result in a string being passed into the directive with the age interpolated.

Answer (score 3):

Expression refers to Angular expression that may or may not contain double curly braces whereas interpolation markup means code inside this curly braces.

Answer (score 1):

**Expression** `{{exp}}`: Something that turns into some value.

**Characteristics:**

1. It is processed by angular.
2. Angular expression are tied to the scope they are in. It has access to the properties of $scope.
3. Doesn't throws error if it has type error.
4. Control flow function(e.g., 'If', 'else' statement etc) not allowed.
5. Accept filter or a filter chain to format the output.

**Interpolation** (process): Process of replacing placeholders in a string with values.

**Characteristics:**

1. In Angular, these placeholders are usually expressions.
2. Result is automatically updated when placeholder changes. If `$scope.message` changes so will interpolation result will change.

Ex:

```
My name is {{ message }}
```

It is interpolated to: `My name is Harry Potter`